# Does an error existe on the next code? it shows error on line 7

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

dataset = pd.read_csv("smogon.csv")
dataset.drop(["url", 'texto'], axis=1, inplace=True)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=1, n_init='auto')
cluster = km.fit_predict(dataset[["moves"]])
dataset["Grupo"] = cluster
print(dataset)
```

it shows (cluster = km.fit_predict(dataset[["moves"]])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
also it shows ( could not convert string to float)

im doing a project with kmeans and pandas and when im trying to do the clustering with the csv file it shows an error but when i do it with another csv file, it doesnt show any problem running it.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include the complete error traceback

Comment: You have to convert your columns from string to numeric.

Comment: @Corralien do you know how I do it? I read bout doing like km.fit_transform or just km.transform? or theres another way to do it

Comment: Use `pandas.factorize` or  `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`. `'moves'` is your only feature? Why do you have only one cluster?

Comment: @Corralien yes it is i gotta cluster from just moves, its from a pokemon list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to convert your column `moves` as numeric:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv("smogon.csv")
dataset.drop(["url", 'texto'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# It does not make sense to have only one cluster...
# There is many documentation to find the best number of clusters (elbow method, ...)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, n_init='auto')
lbe = LabelEncoder()
dataset['moves_num'] = lbe.fit_transform(dataset['moves'])

cluster = km.fit_predict(dataset[['moves_num']])
dataset["Grupo"] = cluster
print(dataset)
```

Comment: THANKS, forgot what clusters were, got confused and thought another thing, yeah maybe ill add more clusters, tysm